# Reference C# type within XML schema?

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, xml-namespaces

Is it possible to reference types within a C# project in an XML Schema file? For validation and intelli-sense I mean...

Lets say I have the following:

```
namespace Example
{
  class myType
  { int test = 0; }
}
```

How would I reference the Example namespace within the schema file so that I can use myType as an element type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly.

There's sort of two ways you can do this though.

The first is to mark your class as `Serializable` and use the [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) to serialize it to XML.  In conjunction with this, you can also use `xsd.exe` to create a schema for your class, and **that** could be used as a type in your (other) schema.  `XmlSerializer` could be used to serialize and deserialize to/from that type.

On a somewhat related note, if you have a **method** that you want to capture in an in XML (as opposed to data types or structures), you can extend some XSLT with C# (or VB.NET, or JavaScript) code.  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf741884(v=vs.110).aspx) has more documentation on how to do that, the basic idea being to use `XsltArgumentList` and `AddExtensionObject` to add that method.  It's also possible to do so directly in the XSLT by using `msxsl:script` (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxaw5z5e(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information on that).

Comment: I just tried xsd.exe with something like:
"xsd D:\somelib.dll /t:SomeNS.SubNS.SomeClass"

However, it seems to go through EVERY class and if I don't have a default constructor (mostly by design on purpose), the whole process fails. Any way to let it ignore reflection errors?

Comment: To serialize/deserialize a class, it MUST have a publicly accessible default (parameterless) constructor - even if that constructor just does nothing and is not used anywhere else.  You should be able to use the /t parameter to XSD.exe to restrict it to just the type(s) you want to serialize.

Comment: Ah,ok. Thank you! Now that I implemented the default constructor for every class, this works great.